# Using AFNetworking and AFHTTPClient to run many URLs through an API - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios6, afnetworking

I'm trying to run a bunch of URLs through the [Clear Read API](http://api.thequeue.org/v1/) (basically extracts the article portion from a URL) and I'm using the [AFNetworking Library](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).

I have an `AFClearReadClient` class which is a subclass of `AFHTTPClient` which I use to simplify interaction with the API. There I set the base URL and the fact it's a JSON request.

```
#import "AFClearReadClient.h"
#import "AFJSONRequestOperation.h"

@implementation AFClearReadClient

+ (AFClearReadClient *)sharedClient {
    static AFClearReadClient *sharedClient = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedClient = [[AFClearReadClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.thequeue.org/v1/clear?url=&format="]];
    });

    return sharedClient;
}

- (id)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url {
    if (self = [super initWithBaseURL:url]) {
        [self registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
        [self setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
    }

    return self;
}
```

I then have a list of articles stored in an `NSDictionary` which I loop through, getting the URL of each article, making the parameters for the impending request from it (the parameters are the GET variables and their values in the base URL, right?), then create the request, and add it to an array holding all the requests.

Then I batch enqueue them (which I don't think I'm doing right). This creates and enqueues each request, which puts them into the process of being acted on, right? But what do I do in the progressBlock? I don't have access to the returned JSON (seemingly, the local vars are just `NSUIntegers`), so I can't do what I'd like to do (save the returned article text).

```
- (void)addArticlesToQueueFromList:(NSDictionary *)articles {
    // Create an array to hold all of our requests to make
    NSMutableArray *requests = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (NSString *key in articles) {
        NSString *articleURL = [[articles objectForKey:key] objectForKey:@"resolved_url"];
        NSDictionary *requestParameters = @{@"url": articleURL,
                                            @"format": @"json"};

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFClearReadClient sharedClient] requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:nil parameters:requestParameters];
        [requests addObject:request];
    }

//  [[AFClearReadClient sharedClient] setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:5];
    [[AFClearReadClient sharedClient] enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperationsWithRequests:[requests copy] progressBlock:^(NSUInteger numberOfFinishedOperations, NSUInteger totalNumberOfOperations) {

    } completionBlock:^(NSArray *operations) {

    }];
}
```

Also, I'm not sure how I should be using the `setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:` method. Should that be done in the `AFClearReadClient` class?

Comment: maybe you should use `enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperations:progressBlock:completionBlock:`

Comment: That really achieves nothing different as a method, it just makes it so you have to create the request operations before that method is used, whereas with the one I used it will create it for you from your requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you are enqueuing requests, and not requestOperations - there is a difference.  Notice the name of the function (enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperations).  You're alright until the request step - you then need to create a AFJSONRequestOperation.  So once you have the request, do the following:

```
AFJSONRequestOperation *requestOperation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request 
 success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON){ ...this is your success block...} 
 failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON){ ...this is your failure block...}];
```

Now you've got a requestOperation and you can go ahead and enqueue that and it should work.

Comment: Are you sure? In the method definition of what I'm using (http://afnetworking.github.com/AFNetworking/Classes/AFHTTPClient.html#//api/name/enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperationsWithRequests:progressBlock:completionBlock:) it says "Creates and enqueues an AFHTTPRequestOperation", which seems to disagree with what you're saying. With your option I'm creating requests, but not in a batch-type method like I'm trying to do.

Comment: Ah ok got it - my bad.  You're right about using requests, but by using that, it sets the success and completion block to nil. What you can do is manually set the success/failure block for each of the requests using `setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:failure:` which should give you access to the response JSON.